# Solve the Distribution equation $xT= 1$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

My Problem is to find all solutions of the distribution equation $xT =1$.

I don't know how to solve it. The solutions should be   $pv\frac1x+c$ , $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

My idea was to create a function like for: Let $T$ a Distribution. $xT=0$ then $T=c\delta$.

But I cant construct a function for my problem and I´m not sure if it´s the right way.

Comment: Hello, mathbob, welcome to MSE. Your question and notation, as it is written now, is not clear. Can you please edit your question so that the question is clear to everyone? Also, may I kindly ask you to use MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: Probably the general solution was intended to be $PV{1\over x}+c\cdot \delta$, for arbitrary constant $c$. You can check that $x\cdot u=0$ implies that the support of $u$ is contained in $\{0\}$, and we know all distributions supported at $0$. Checking that $x\cdot PV{1\over x}=1$ is direct... by applying both to a test function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distributions need something to act on, so let $\phi$ be a test function. Denote the action of $T$ on $\phi$ by $\langle T,\phi \rangle$.

Functions act on test functions by integration, so that $\langle 1,\phi \rangle = \displaystyle \int_{\mathbb R} 1 \cdot \phi(x) \, dx$.

The distribution $xT$ is defined via the rule $\langle xT,\phi \rangle = \langle T,x\phi \rangle$.

The question then becomes, what distribution $T$ satisfies
$$\langle T,x\phi \rangle = \int_{\mathbb R} \phi(x) \, dx ?$$
You can get $x \phi$ in the integrand via
$$\int_{\mathbb R} \phi(x) \, dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{\mathbb R \setminus [-\epsilon,\epsilon]} \phi(x) \, dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{\mathbb R \setminus [-\epsilon,\epsilon]} \frac{x\phi(x)}{x} \, dx.$$
The principal value distribution $\mathrm{pv} \frac 1x$ is defined via the formula
$$\langle \mathrm{pv} \frac 1x,\phi \rangle = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{\mathbb R \setminus [-\epsilon,\epsilon]} \frac{\phi(x)}{x} \, dx$$
so that $$ \int_{\mathbb R} \phi(x) \, dx = \langle \mathrm{pv} \frac 1x,x\phi \rangle.$$
Thus $\mathrm{pv} \frac 1x$ satisfies $xT = 1$.

If $T$ is an arbitrary distribution with $xT = 1$ it follows that $x(T - \mathrm{pv} \frac 1x) = 0$, implying that $T - \mathrm{pv} \frac 1x = c \delta$ for some $c$, where $\delta$ is the delta distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. So the trick ist first to look on the distribution $\langle T,\Phi \rangle $. Then write the 1 as $\frac{x}{x} $. After this use the definition of pv and write it back into a distribution. Or did I understand it wrong?

Comment: That's right, except first use the principal value then write $1 = \frac xx$.

Comment: Oh yeah, got it. For me distribution is a difficult theme, because I dont hear pde and functional analysis in my university. For this seminar we "only" need knowledge from analysis1-3 and ode. But actually with some practise distributions should be easier than now.